# Delay index build until SQL Server table load is complete with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I have a large table that I am updating.  Is it possible to disable index updates on the destination table until the load is complete?  It seems like a waste for it to be constantly updating the index with each commit.

I can just drop and recreate the index before and after the load, I just want to know if there is a quick way to configure that in the OLEDB or SQL Server destination.

Server is Windows Server 2003 Datacenter Edition, running SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition with SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER INDEX IndexName ON Table DISABLE

I'm not sure that doing this will help you though - the index needs to be updated sooner or later.  Perhaps you would disable auto stats update until the full load is done.